# How can I access the View controller created by Storyboard?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xcode4.5

I intend to do something similar to YouTube's interface which has a side menu displayed when the menu button is pressed, and change the view controller when a different page is pressed.

I have all of my view controllers created in Storyboard but I can't find a way to access those. When I use instance:

```
[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuController"]
```

it creates a new `MenuController` instead of the one that is presented from the Storyboard. I would like to use the existing one. Is there a way to do that or do I have to initialize and setup everything programmatically at startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do. You're asking how to access View controllers created by storyboard, but it looks like you already know how to do that. If you instead want to access a MenuController you already created sometime before in the app lifecycle, you can just save it in a property, maybe in the AppDelegate for example, so that you can retrieve it when you need it

Comment: So what happened is that MenuController that is being presented is not the one I instantiated. 

Is there a way to access the menuController that is being presented instead of instantiate a menuController from storyboard (instantiate from storyboard will create a new instance)? or I just have to do that from the very beginning?

Comment: The easiest way to do that would be to create a `@property` in your `AppDelegate` which will store the `MenuController` and then from everywhere in your code you can access that property